# how can i sort this either in sql query or arraylist?

Tags: java, android, sql, sorting, arraylist

here is the query i am using i want sorted result like 11/2017, 12/2017,3/2018 5/2018

and also if it cant be done in query then if i can do it in android java arraylist if possible please help

[image: here is the query i am using]

Comment: SELECT distinct monthyear from notes
ORDER BY monthyear ASC,

Comment: How is monthyear stored? is it, for example, a date field? You should also stated what flavour of SQL e.g. mySQL. It looks like T-SQL being used. If you execute the following:   exec sp_help 'notes'   you should be able to view how it is stored.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed it gives same result as it is in image this is asc order

Comment: @QHarr it is like shown in image month/year

Comment: Try to store dates in a **proper format**. I.e.: `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare( String d1, String d2) {
    if(d1.equals(d2)) return 0;
    try {
      Date date = sdf.parse(d1);
      Date date2 = sdf.parse(d2);
      return date.before(date2)? -1:1;
    }catch (ParseException exception){
      Log.e("Date compare ->", exception.getMessage(), exception);
      return  0;
    }
  }
});
```

If you use lambda you can use a little shorter version:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
        Collections.sort(list, (Comparator<String>) (d1, d2) -> {
            if(d1.equals(d2)) return 0;

            try {
                Date date = sdf.parse(d1);
                Date date2 = sdf.parse(d2);
                return date.before(date2)? -1:1;
            }catch (ParseException exception){
                Log.e("Date compare ->", exception.getMessage(), exception);
                return  0;
            }
        });
```

Android API level 24 let you to use list.sort method:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
        list.sort((Comparator<String>) (d1, d2) -> {
            if(d1.equals(d2)) return 0;

            try {
                Date date = sdf.parse(d1);
                Date date2 = sdf.parse(d2);
                return date.before(date2)? -1:1;
            }catch (ParseException exception){
                Log.e("Date compare ->", exception.getMessage(), exception);
                return  0;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT distinct monthyear FROM notes ORDER BY date(monthyear) DESC
```

Note : Here, you want to order by date so you need to use **date()**. And if you want **date and time both**, you need to use **datetime()**

Comment: it says 'date' is not a recognized built-in function name.